# Python init class with __enter__

Tags: python

I have four variables `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password` in my `User` class and I'm trying to init my class using this method:

```
with User(email, first_name, last_name, password) as user:
```

and here is the `__enter__` method:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return
```

now when I debug the `return` statement in the `__enter__` method I can see that the variables were sent successfully but when I debug the `user` instance I get `None`
[image]
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with User(email, first_name, last_name, password) as user:` is (roughly) equivalent to

```
u = User(email, first_name, last_name, password)
user = u.__enter__()
```

Since `__enter__` returns `None`, that's what `user` is bound to.

If you want `user` to be the instance `u`, `__enter__` needs to return `self`.

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```